# Frequency response of a series RL circuit

Tags: resistors, filter, inductor, frequency-response

I connected the larger coil of [this](https://www.jaycar.com.au/aerial-ferrite-rod-with-coil/p/LF1020) ferrite rod aerial (which according to it's datasheet, should have an inductance of 200 uH) in series with a 10 ohm resistor and just left the smaller coil open. When I ran network analysis (frequency response analysis) of the circuit with an ADALM2000, I noticed these 2 troughs in the plot at 391 kHz and 1.41 MHz which from my understanding, shouldn't be present in the frequency response of a series LC circuit. Does anyone know why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: even if you did not connect any, your circuit has capacitance, it will never be a pure RL circuit, if you can measure the parasitic capacitance and see if those poles match a value of that order.